# How to parallelize a backtesting for a trading strategy based on a machine learning model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, parallel-processing, scikit-learn, algorithmic-trading

For the purpose of backtesting a trading strategy, based on a machine learning model, I wanted to compute the retraining procedure of the model in parallel.

> <sub>Now my question is:</sub>

### Is there an opportunity to improve the speed of my algorithm?

It is implemented in python using scikit-learn. The procedure of backtesting is defined as follows:

1. Train the model on 900 ( the first three years ) data points
2. Make a prediction for the next day t+1
3. Retrain the model on the next datapoint t+1
4. again make a prediction with the model for the day t+2
5. Retrain the model ....
6. make a prediction ...

Simply, make a prediction for the next data point and retrain the model on this data point. Then do this till the current day ( last data point ). For some stock predictions, this could be up to 5000 data points, which means by starting this backtesting procedure with a model trained on the first 900 data points, I need to retrain and predict the model 4100 times.

To parallelize the procedure I am using multiprocessing. I have the chance to use a server, that provides 40 CPU kernels. So what I am doing is:

1. Divide the data points 4100 in 40 parts
2. Start a process on every kernel which runs the procedure for 1 part
3. after finishing the procedure, write the result on disk
4. collect every result and put it together

Python Code:

```
pool = Pool()
results = []

for i in range(len(parts)):
    try:
        result = pool.apply_async(classify_parts,[parts[i], parts[i+1]])
        results.append(result)
    except IndexError:
        continue

for result in results:
    result.get()
```

The method *classify_parts*, starts the procedure for the given range.
For instance, if I have 500 data points and will start the whole backtesting by training the model on 100 data points, I have 400 data points ( days ) left for the backtesting, which means:

1. divide 400 data points in 40 parts [10,20,30,...,380,390,400]
2. start a process on every kernel:

   - `classify_parts( 10, 20 )`, ... , `classify_parts( 390, 400 )`
3. collect the results from disk and put them together

Hopefully I could illustrated my concept in a clear manner.

> So my biggest **question** is, **if there is another more efficient way of doing backtesting with a machine learning model, that is retrained on every next data point ( day )?** Because with this concept, one backtesting procedure for 5000 data points runs more than 10 minutes.

**Maybe incremental / online learning is here the way to go?**

Comment: What model are you using ? I do not think you can expect to reduce your loss efficiently with independent runs

Comment: I am using a Multi-layer Perceptron with ‘lbfgs’ (is an optimizer in the family of quasi-Newton methods) as solver and ‘relu’, (the rectified linear unit function, returns f(x) = max(0, x)) as activation function. Implemented by scikit-learn. Input-Layer -- Hidden-Layer(100 neurons) -- Output-Layer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, this is not parallelizing the process scheduling.

If in doubts, one may revisit theory details on **SERIAL**, **PARALLEL** and **"just"-CONCURRENT** process scheduling before reading further.

### Put in plain English

Things may go into **SERIAL** mode of operations by-principle ( by intent ) or by some sort of resource-limitation. If one is to type a word "**`parallel`**" on a keyboard, the letters <kbd>**`p`**</kbd>, next <kbd>**`a`**</kbd>, next <kbd>**`r`**</kbd> ... etc have to be touched SERIAL-ly, one after another, otherwise the input process fails to provide the guaranteed, correct result - i.e. the word "**`parallel`**" on screen ( and let's assume we forget about a chance to use a <kbd>`Shift`</kbd> key for the clarity of this example ).

Anyone may test, what gets produced, if one tries to press all the keys at the same moment, or in pairs, or while a cat is standing at your keyboard ... all additional ideas are welcome for hands-on experimentation.

### SERIAL processes cannot go faster

In any other circumstances than by getting faster processing-resources and/or by lowering inter-process transport-delays ( or in case a new, smarter algorithm exists and is known to the kind programmer and yet additionally shows to be feasible to get implemented on resources available ).

---

### What is indeed a PARALLEL process?

On the other hand, some things must be organised so as to happen right in the opposite end of the spectra -- if all things simply have to start + happen + finish at the same time, otherwise the results from the process are considered wrong. What could be brought as an example?

- imagine a few visually simply "readable" examples - the show of Red Arrows - a group of 9 jet planes, which displays figures and manoeuvres of high pilotage

  [image]

  or Frecce Tricolori

  [image]

  where all planes move at the same time exactly the given ( same ) way, otherwise the lovely show would fail.
- imagine a concert, that has to take place. This is exactly the ultimately **`PARALLEL`** process and one would immediately recognise how devastating that would be, if it were not

  [image]
- imagine a robot-control system for several degrees-of-freedom, where all motion has to be carried out and has to be kept under a control of a closed-loop [ actor - detector - actuator ] subsystem in sync, coordinated for all of the several programming-controlled axes. The system must control all the NC-axes together as a PARALLEL process -- otherwise the robot-arm will never be able to follow the black-line - [the defined, curved, spatio-temporal trajectory in +4-D space ( best to view in real-time ).](https://youtu.be/80iIhfjTm5I?t=2m11s)

  [image]

The robot-control example shows, that the farther we move from the aerobatics or the symphony examples, for which we have some direct experience ( or where one's imagination can provide some comprehension ), the PARALLEL process-scheduling may seem harder to sense or to realise, but the symphony seems to be the best one to remind, when questioning if a problem is indeed a truly PARALLEL or not.

Just ask yourself, what would happen, if just half of the ensemble comes in due time to start playing at 19:00 sharp, or what would happen, if some of the violins plays at an accelerated speed... or what would happen, if the players will start playing just one note, in a sequence and let his/her left side-neighbour to play his/her note, waiting until the order of playing gets back to the same player to perform his/her next note in the concert. Correct, that would be pure-SERIAL scheduling. )

---

### So, would 40-CPU-cores allow to somehow accelerate my problem?

The problem still depends on the processing.

[image]

If the learning-method ( in an undisclosed [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ) has a built in dependence, for example if `classify_parts( 20, 30 )` needs to get some input or a piece of information, generated from a "previous" step in `classify_parts( 10, 20 )`, then the answer is no.

If the learning-method is independent, in the above defined sense, then there is a chance to schedule the process as a "just"-CONCURRENT and benefit from the fact that there are more "free"-lanes on the highway to allow cars run in not just one lane, but allow one to overtake another, slower one, on the way from start to finish. A rugby team can move from city A to city B "faster", if there is 2 or 3 or more 4-seat cars available in the city A stadium, than if there is just 1 and it has to go there and back and forth to move all the players successfully to city B.

Next, even if there are cars enough to move to city B for all players, the duration would be uncomfortably high in case, there is just one lane road from A to B and there is a high traffic in the opposite direction from B to A ( not allowing to overtake ) and a single tractor, also going from A to B, but at a speed of 1 mph.

### Warning: ( if in a search for really FAST PROCESSING, the more for the FASTEST POSSIBLE one )

Still, even if there are none of the above sketched "external" obstacles, one has to be very careful, not to lose the benefits available from "bigger" machine + "wider" highways ( more resources available ) for a **"just"-CONCURRENT** process scheduling.

Yes, the problem here is related with programming tools.

Python can help a lot for fast prototyping, but beware for the Global Interpreter Lock ( **GIL** ) code-execution implications.

In your case, using a **`Pool()`** of 40-threads might look attractive, but will still wait for a GIL-acquisition/release and ALL THE WORK WILL turn to be `SERIAL` again, just due to omission to notice the known GIL-mechanics on a **`Pool()`** of python-threads.

Yes, there are other more promising alternatives, like a **`ThreadPool()`** et al, but not only the code-related GIL-stepping is devastating your efforts to accelerate the speed of the process, but also the shared data-structures is a problem to watch and to avoid. Additionally, the **`Pool()`** naively-replicated environments may grow beyond one's system RAM capacities and the swapping mechanism will yield such attempt to accelerate the process totally un-usable at all. **Share nothing**, otherwise your dream to accelerate processing will lose on sharing-mechanics and you are back on the square No.1.

The best way is to design the code as independent processes, that have zero-sharing, non-blocking ( MEM, IO ) operations.

### Given all that above, the 40-CPU-cores may help to accelerate the "just"-CONCURRENT process.

Comment: First, thank you user3666197 for the introduction, examples and overview of SERIAL, PARALLEL and "just"-CONCURRENT process scheduling. The main purpose for choosing the multi processing approach is the fact, that one can use separate memory space. Correct me if i am wrong: So the GIL-mechanics are not taken into account here, due to the fact, that there won't be any writing procedures to the same memory space.

Comment: The Learning procedure is completely independent i.e. classifiy_one(20,30) does not need the input of (10,20). Thus, this follows your Highway-Analogy with 40 lanes. Could you please explain in  more detail what you mean with overtake the lane of a process. In my concept I think of 40 several process that are running on several lanes and not sharing anything.

Comment: The core Problem in this approach is the fact, that if the data for the training procedure increases, the process time increases also. So maybe it would be better to divide the last parts with more data ( from my 400 data points example this would be the parts from 300-400) into several processes and let the first parts ( 100-300) be bigger. Due to the fact, that the first ones are not as time consuming as the other ones.

Comment: Again thank you for your effort in your answer! So if we assume the code is designed as complete independent processes, that have zero sharing, non blocking (MEM, IO) operations, is there another approach in the field of backtesting with Machine Learning Models, which is the usually one and more efficient and natural to the task ? And could you tell me, why there is shared memory with using the Pool() class in python? Cause that could by the only blocking operations i can think of.

Comment: Well, the core issue is in training the model, there it is not so easy, if possible at all, to "split" any task into a "just"-CONCURRENT learning. Even if separable in the fight to reduce the PTIME / EXPTIME envelope of the learning process, the growing data-sizes are keen to kill you in PSPACE / EXPSPACE dimension, right due to the **`Pool()`** having to replicate the environment state ( yes, 40-times all the data-structures et al ) for all your processes, which may get you out of in-RAM processing sooner than one expects...

Comment: As I think of the discussed approach again and reading your points, the crucial facts are: Not sure if real concurrent learning is possible at all for this approach; Bottleneck in-Ram capacity; What would you propose as an alternative backtesting procedure with ML ?